# Build the Mountain Car Environment using coupled inheritance and type annotations

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, type-hinting

This code builds the environment for the standard [Mountain Car Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_car_problem) of reinforcement learning.

I'm using Python 3.9 with PyCharm and I'm wishing to use type annotations throughout. I'm trying to find a good pattern for when there are two or more groups of inheriting classes and objects from one group are referenced by the other group. The problem is when there are methods that exist solely in the parent class but used by the child classes. Type-checking (in PyCharm) isn't smart enough to realise a coupled child class has been returned (example below)

I've found 3 ways round this:

1. Repeat the method in the child class and disable the type hint. (repetition, risk)
2. Repeat the method in the child class and use `isinstance()`. (repetition, inefficient)
3. Make the parent class `NonTabularEnvironment` generic, accepting a `TypeVar` for `State` (over-engineered? cryptic? or actually correct?).

I see this pattern a lot in my code and I'm coding on my own so I'd like to know what other people think is the right way to do this.

By using real code, as required to post here, there is quite a lot of code required to demonstrate the problem although I've trimmed some of the non-relevant methods. Comments on any aspect are welcome and feel free to give negative feedback. However I do want to use type-annotations throughout and I do like to have each object in a separate file.

The code with the design issue I'm trying to apply the right approach for is in the script below where the type-checking fails. The object returned will in fact always be a `State` but the type-checker thinks it could be a `NonTabularState` so I think my Class code is deficient:

```
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.environment_parameters import EnvironmentParameters
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.environment import Environment
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.state import State

environment_parameters: EnvironmentParameters = EnvironmentParameters()
environment: Environment = Environment(environment_parameters)
environment.build()

# PROBLEM: PyCharm type checker: Expected type 'State', got 'NonTabularState' instead
state: State = environment.draw_start_state()
print(state)
```

There are two levels of the code:

- `Environment` is the code for the problem (a mountain car) this inherits from `NonTabularEnvironment`
- The `Environment` can be in a state.
- The mountain car `State` inherits from `NonTabularState`.
- The start state of the mountain car problem is drawn from a `StartStateDistribution` which itself inherits from `Distribution`. This just contains a method that returns a random start state but I've included the code anyway.

#### Parent level: `NonTabularEnvironment`:

```
from typing import Optional
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from mdp import common
from mdp.model.environment.environment import Environment
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.non_tabular_state import NonTabularState
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.non_tabular_action import NonTabularAction
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.dims import Dims


class NonTabularEnvironment(Environment, ABC):
    """An abstract Environment with continuous states but discrete actions"""
    def __init__(self, environment_parameters: common.EnvironmentParameters):
        """
        :param environment_parameters: the parameters specific to the specific environment e.g. number_of_cars
        """
        super().__init__(environment_parameters)

        # action list and action lookup
        self.actions: list[NonTabularAction] = []

        # dimensions
        self._dims: Dims = Dims()

        # Distributions
        self._start_state_distribution: Optional[common.Distribution[NonTabularState]] = None

    def build(self):
        self._build_actions()
        self._build_dimensions()
        self._start_state_distribution: common.Distribution[NonTabularState] = self._get_start_state_distribution()

    @abstractmethod
    def _build_actions(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _build_dimensions(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_start_state_distribution(self) -> common.Distribution[NonTabularState]:
        pass

    def draw_start_state(self) -> NonTabularState:
        return self._start_state_distribution.draw_one()
```

#### Child level: `Environment` (the concrete Mountain Car problem)

```
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.non_tabular_environment import NonTabularEnvironment
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.dimension.float_dimension import FloatDimension
from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.dimension.category_dimension import CategoryDimension

from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.state import State
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.action import Action
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.environment_parameters import EnvironmentParameters
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.start_state_distribution import StartStateDistribution
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.enums import Dim


class Environment(NonTabularEnvironment):
    def __init__(self, environment_parameters: EnvironmentParameters):
        super().__init__(environment_parameters)

        # downcast actions so properties appear on intellisense
        self.actions: list[Action] = self.actions
        self._start_state_distribution: StartStateDistribution = self._start_state_distribution

    def _build_actions(self):
        self.actions = [
            Action(acceleration=-1.0),
            Action(acceleration=0.0),
            Action(acceleration=1.0)
        ]

    def _build_dimensions(self):
        self._dims.state_float[Dim.POSITION] = FloatDimension(min=-1.2, max=0.5)
        self._dims.state_float[Dim.VELOCITY] = FloatDimension(min=-0.07, max=0.07)
        self._dims.action_category[Dim.ACCELERATION] = CategoryDimension(possible_values=len(self.actions))

    def _get_start_state_distribution(self) -> StartStateDistribution[State]:
        return StartStateDistribution(self._dims)

    # Potential non-generic workarounds - override the method in every child Class
    # def draw_start_state(self) -> State:
        # Option 1
        # return super().draw_start_state()   # type: ignore

        # Option 2
        # state: NonTabularState = super().draw_start_state()
        # state: State
        # return state

        # Option 3
        # state = super().draw_start_state()
        # if isinstance(state, State):
        #     return state
```

#### Parent level: `NonTabularState`

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

import numpy as np

from mdp.model.environment.state import State


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class NonTabularState(State, ABC):
    floats: np.ndarray = field(init=False, repr=False, hash=False, compare=False)
    categories: np.ndarray = field(init=False, repr=False, hash=False, compare=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        # from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53756788
        object.__setattr__(self, "floats", np.array(self._get_floats(), dtype=float))
        object.__setattr__(self, "categories", np.array(self._get_categories(), dtype=object))

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_floats(self) -> list[float]:
        pass

    def _get_categories(self) -> list:
        return []
```

#### Child level: `State` (of Mountain Car)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.non_tabular_state import NonTabularState


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class State(NonTabularState):
    position: float
    velocity: float

    def _get_floats(self) -> list[float]:
        return [self.position, self.velocity]
```

#### Parent level: `Distribution` (generalised)

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


T = TypeVar('T')


class Distribution(Generic[T], ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def draw_one(self) -> T:
        pass
```

#### Child level: `StateStateDistribution` (for the Mountain Car problem)

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

import numpy as np

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from mdp.model.environment.non_tabular.dims import Dims

from mdp.common.distribution.distribution import Distribution
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.enums import Dim
from mdp.scenarios.mountain_car.model.state import State


class StartStateDistribution(Distribution[State]):
    def __init__(self, dims: Dims):
        self._position_min = dims.state_float[Dim.POSITION].min
        self._position_max = dims.state_float[Dim.POSITION].max

    def draw_one(self) -> State:
        # "Samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open interval [low, high)"
        random_position = np.random.uniform(low=self._position_min, high=self._position_max)
        return State(is_terminal=False, position=random_position, velocity=0.0)
```

Comment: I made an edit changing the title to something that I think describes the code. Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you. I had to alter it slightly to say that the code given only builds the environment and stressing the need for type annotations. Without type annotations the existing code works just fine so I feel it has to be in there to highlight the issue I want help with.

Comment: `class NonTabularState(State, ABC)` and `class State(NonTabularState)` seem to inherit from each other. Is that correct?  Also, have you tried using `TypeVar` with the `bound` keyword arg? (See [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id25))

Comment: @RootTwo thanks for the interest. NonTabularState inherits from a more abstract class still also called State. NonTabularEnvironment also inherits from a more abstract class still also called Environment. I have tried using TypeVar with Bound and yes that does resolve the PyCharm type checker issue. Do you think using Generics in a simple case like this is appropriate?

Comment: I have been trying to decide if covariance=True is required then too. As with non-generics I would to retain being able to pass a concrete Mountain Car Environment with a concrete Mountain Car State into functions taking an abstract Environment. PyCharm flags nothing but MyPy does flag this. [link](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7049). However, I think this is not prohibited in PEP 484. It's only prohibited for functions, not methods. And in PEP 483 it says "It is possible to **declare** the variance for user defined generic types"